# Monty Hall Game Unable to get an exact probability

Tags: java, math, probability

I was curious about the Monty Hall problem and tried to implement the Monty Hall game given at:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Problem statement reads. Suppose you're on a game show, and you're given the choice of three doors: Behind one door is a car; behind the others, goats. You pick a door, say No. 1, and the host, who knows what's behind the doors, opens another door, say No. 3, which has a goat. He then says to you, "Do you want to pick door No. 2?" Is it to your advantage to switch your choice?

However, my success percentage by switching the door come out to be almost 75% rather than the usual 66%. Can you find why?

```
//This is the results after 100 million iterations
//Result
//Staying with the choice
//0.2500521243
//Changing the choice
//0.7499478459

public class Monty {
public static void main(String args[]){
    someMethod();
}

public static void someMethod() {

    int TOTAL_ITERATIONS = 100000000;

    int trial = 0;
    int win = 0;

    Random random = new Random();

    List<Integer> initialDoorConfig = new ArrayList<>();
    initialDoorConfig.add(1);
    initialDoorConfig.add(0);
    initialDoorConfig.add(0);

    while(trial != TOTAL_ITERATIONS){

        //Ensure Randomness
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        random.setSeed(timestamp.getTime());


        //Create Random Door Configuration
        Collections.shuffle(initialDoorConfig);



        //Game Play Begins

        //Player Chooses Door
        int playerChoiceDoorIndex = new Random().nextInt(initialDoorConfig.size());

        //Host Chooses Door
        int hostChoiceDoorIndex = new Random().nextInt(initialDoorConfig.size());


        /*
        Condition 1:  initialDoorConfig.get(hostChoiceDoorIndex) == 1
        Reason: Makes sure the door chosen by host does not have a car behind it.

        Condition 2: hostChoiceDoorIndex == playerChoiceDoorIndex
        Reason: Makes sure hosts door choice and players door choice wasn't the same

        Having met these conditions we can be sure they game can be played.

         */
        if(initialDoorConfig.get(hostChoiceDoorIndex) == 1 && hostChoiceDoorIndex == playerChoiceDoorIndex){
            //If the conditions are not met, they game is not a the right game we are interested in.
            continue;
        }else{
            //Game can be played and increment the game index
            trial = trial + 1;

            //Assuming player will always stay with the door he choose before
            if(initialDoorConfig.get(playerChoiceDoorIndex) == 1){
                win = win + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Staying with the choice");
    System.out.printf("%.10f", (float)win/TOTAL_ITERATIONS);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Changing the choice");
    System.out.printf("%.10f", ((float)TOTAL_ITERATIONS - win)/TOTAL_ITERATIONS);

}
```

}

Comment: `//Ensure Randomness` why do you think re-setting the seed every time is *more* random than using a seed? A pRNG is tailored to generate a *sufficiently random* sequence with a single seed. When you change it, that's more random in the sense that it's a you are actually subverting the mathematically modelled algorithm for a well-defined pRNG sequence. The *result* of that is not necessarily that you would get a *better* random distribution - likely it's worse.

Comment: Did my answer fix the program? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the host in your code chooses a door randomly, which is different from the actual game, where he always chooses a door with a goat. I am not good enough at maths to explain why not counting the invalid games changes the probability to 0.75.

But your program will give the correct answer if you simulate what the host *actually* does:

```
int hostChoiceDoorIndex = 0;
for (; hostChoiceDoorIndex < 3 ; hostChoiceDoorIndex++) {
    if (hostChoiceDoorIndex != playerChoiceDoorIndex && initialDoorConfig.get(hostChoiceDoorIndex) == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I am not good enough at maths to explain why not counting the invalid games changes the probability to 0.75.*" honestly, I struggled with this *for years*. I finally found an easy way to explain it to myself - write down every single possible combination of where the reward is (door 1, 2, 3) and subsequent choices (door 1-stay with one, door 1-choose 2, door 1-choose 2, etc), finally count how many times you win when switching vs how many times you win by staying. That is how I finally grasped it.